# PyQt using QLineEdit as cellWidget in a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

So I created a QTableWidget which is filled with QComboBoxes and QLineEdits. My QComboBoxes work perfectly fine, but my QLineEdits for whatever reason don't display the text properly.

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()  
tableItem = QtGui.QLineEdit(  )
tableItem.setText( "Testing" )
self.table.setCellWidget(row, 1, tableItem )
```

Now I tried testing it to see if the value resides in the table...and sure enough if I use tableItem.text() I get "Testing" back.  I'm just not sure why the lineEdit displays nothing  when I run the UI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example, with the QLineEdit working just fine.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
table = QtGui.QTableWidget(2,2)

tableItem = QtGui.QLineEdit()
tableItem.setText( "Testing" )
table.setCellWidget(0, 0, tableItem )

comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
table.setCellWidget(1,1, comboBox)

table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Basically, all I changed was giving the table a size. You can do this at its creation like I did, or with `table.setRowCount()`.

And of course, for a table with r rows, make sure you don't insert anything *at* row r. It goes from 0 to r-1.

Comment: Hmm...I already did a setRowCount() and setColumnCount() but it still didn't help the QLineEdit show.  I've used QLineEdit regularly before, I'm just wondering if it's something stupid that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Are you certain that `row` has the correct value? Is your code sample in a for loop? If my example works for you but doesn't solve your situation, maybe you should provide a little more code/context.

Comment: Yes I made it print out the row and the value is correct.  After looking at my code some more, I realized that I should've been querying the table to get my value back instead of my variable.  So I added a few lines of code and I now realize that my item.text() comes back as NoneType.                                     self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()  
tableItem = QtGui.QLineEdit(  )
tableItem.setText( "Testing" )
self.table.setCellWidget(row, 1, tableItem )

item = self.table.item( row, 1 )
print '-----my stupid item is -----'
print row
print item.text()